# Fetch a range of dates using jQueryUI datepicker and php, in Spanish

Tags: java, php, jquery, datepicker, strftime

I'm trying to save a range of dates that will be filled in by the user, via 2 datepickers that were previously translated to Spanish.

The problem is that when I use `strtotime()` on the dates it takes the month as the day and vice versa.

Example:
I choose day 27 month 05 and year 2017, but the return value is an incorrect date format since the month is 27. If I choose day 01 month 05 year 2017 then it shows in the array as day 05 month 01 and year 2017.

Here are the functions I use to take the dates from the input texts, and to generate the range between the dates

```
function takedates() {
    if(isset($_POST['repS'])){      
        $dateStart = $_POST['txtdesde'];
        $dateEnd = $_POST['txthasta'];
        $fechaArray = generafechas($dateStart,$dateEnd);
    }

function generafechas($date1,$date2){
    $fecharray = array();
    if (is_string($date1) === true){            
        $deit1 = strftime("%d-%m-%Y",strtotime($date1));            
    }
    if (is_string($date2) === true){            
        $date2 = strftime("%d-%m-%Y",strtotime($date2));            
    }
    do {
        $fecharray[] = date("m-d-Y", $date1);
         $date1 = strtotime("+1 day", $date1);  
    } while($date1 <= $date2);
    return $fecharray;
}
?>
```

My question is: How do i fill the array with the dates in the spanish date format?

PS: I've already used `setLocale(LC_TIME,'es_ES')` in the file where I'm using these functions, and the input shows the dates like this "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: Please write question in English

Comment: I believe there is a spanish version of this website where you can post this question. This needs to be translated to English if you wish to keep it here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this site requires that you post your questions in *English* only. Please translate this yourself; someone else translating for you will not help you understand comments and answers, or respond to feedback.

Comment: Yo creo tú publicas en la versión en español de este sitio web.  (In case he/she can't read English)

Comment: oh ok, well i can translate it, i didn't know there was a spanish version of this, thought it was the same site, thanks

Comment: but anyway it is an english/spanish issue that i'm trying to solve here, because of dateformat, so i don't think it would be too likely that you've had this issue,  i'll translate it anyways

Comment: Thank you bro, for Español try next: URL http://es.stackoverflow.com/, Monshe Katz answers looks good, only U.S.A. use the mm/dd/yyyy format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtotime` does not take your locale into consideration when parsing the datetime string. If you use a date separated by slashes it is assumed to be American-style `m/d/y`. If you use a date separated by periods (or dashes if the year is four digits), it is assumed to be rest-of-the-world-style (`d.m.y` or `d-m-Y`). (Note that if you only use a two digit year and use dashes, PHP will try try to parse it as `y-m-d`.)

Instead of `strtotime`, you should use [`date-create-from-format` / `DateTime::createFromFormat`](https://php.net/datetime.createfromformat) to get a `DateTime` object, then build your date string from that.

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENTS:** In order to get the output you want, you need to use the `intl` extension's [`IntlDateFormatter` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) to make the output.

To modify your code above (untested):

```
function generafechas($date1,$date2){
    $fecharray = array();

    if (is_string($date1) && is_string($date2)){
        // These lines assume the input is formatted `day-month-year`,
        // with 2-digit day and month, and 4-digit year.
        $date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date1)
        $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date2)
    } else {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Must provide two date strings');
    }

    // Create the formatter
    $formatter = IntlDateFormatter::create('es_ES', null, null, null, null, "d 'de' MMMM 'del' yyyy");

    do {
        // This line prints the first date in the format you chose above
        $fecharray[] = $formatter->format($date1);
        $date1->add(new DateInterval("P1D")); // `P1D` means "Duration of 1 Day" in the ISO 8601 standard
    } while($date1 <= $date2);

    return $fecharray;
}
```

If you provide the Locale along with the data, you can change what format string is used in `createFromFormat` as needed.

Comment: Thank you Very much for that answer, but i'm working on a database with existing data and i don't have acces to changing it, that's why i have to make an array to Select a Range of dates, because the dates in the database are inserted as Varchar and in this format example: "18 de mayo del 2016 " so it's a pain, Anyways thank's for the info

Comment: @Sojansons All you need to do is change the output format. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Oh my, Thank you Very much that really works, i had found a workaround but this saved me lines and it's way better !  thanks again.